# How do VoIP apps connect users with no real IP addresses together?

Tags: networking, voip

I want to know how two computers with VoIP software can be connected to each other and exchange voice data without having an external IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need an static IP address only if you were trying to connect the two to each other directly. The VOIP server acts as a go-between.

Example:

- Person 1 and Person 2 are trying to get into a VOIP call
- They both register with the VOIP server with their IDs.
- When one ID places a call to another, the there is a connection between the two, with the server in between, but not directly with each other.

SIP (Session Initiation Protocol) is usually the Protocol used for VOIP. There is a SIP registrar, which is the server. You can establish your own SIP server using [Asterisk's](http://www.asterisk.org/) free solution. SIP actually makes it possible to directly connect peers. However, this isnt possible over the internet where people dont have static IPS

Software like skype use a similar workflow. The skype client tries to connect the peers. When it cant, it uses something like [UDP Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching).

Answer (score 0):

Every computer in the internet has an external IP.
The internet works that way.

There are numerous pages on the internet, where you can see your 'external IP'.
Regarding the voice exchange: They connect to a server and that server either does the relaying himself, or exchanges the IP information between the clients, who are then left to create a connection among themselves.

Comment: When I say external IP, I mean the unique IP address nobody else has, and which can be used to connect to your computer only. Many ISPs don't give their users such addresses, so they can't be directly connected to.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I seem to have misunderstood. But that's a 'fixed IP', actually.
On a side note, the information still is correct. The server either relays the data itself, or exchanges the 'current IP' information between the clients, so they can connect to each other directly.

Answer (score 0):

The actual data of a VoIP call is carried over RTP, which really only takes 24-64Kbps (depending upon codec) and requires UDP addresses going each way.  Occasional RTCP packets are sent to report status, metrics, etc, but are not really needed.
SIP is used for call setup and teardown.

There is always a network address between two VoIP endpoints, comprised of the IP address and the VoIP socket.

And yes, you could proxy RTP over some other transport protocol, or tunnel (through http?), etc.